# regular expression for validating exponential value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression:

```
/^(([1-9]+\.[0-9]*)|([1-9]*\.[0-9]+)|([1-9]+))([eE])([-+]?[0-9]+)?$/
```

to validate exponential value.it is working fine.But some values like 21E,31E it is considering as exponential value but values like 09E it is considering non exponential value.
Can we have the solution for this ,So that it ll consider all values like 21E,31E,09E as non-exponential value.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of providing a few counterexamples, can't you tell us precisely what you consider valid strings ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? As a general rule, it's a bad idea to do number manipulation with regexp. You'll never get it exactly right.

Comment: "You'll never get it exactly right": nonsense !

Comment: Anyway, just read your regexp back to yourself, saying what each part means.

Answer (score 1):

A mantissa is either a 0, or a nonzero digit possibly followed by digits.

`0|([1-9][0-9]*)`

A fractional part is a possibly empty string of digits.

`[0-9]*`

A real number is a mantissa followed by a point followed by a fractional part.

`(0|([1-9][0-9]*))\.[0-9]*`

An exponent is e followed by a mantissa.

`(eE)(0|([1-9][0-9]*))`

A scientific number is a real number optionally followed by an exponent

`(0|([1-9][0-9]*))\.[0-9]*([eE](0|([1-9][0-9]*)))?`

Some variants are possible, as the OP didn't give a complete specification.

Comment: Why do you consider `1e01` to be invalid?

Comment: @torazaburo: my choice, the OP didn't specify. (I demand the use of the decimal point and in the C language, `01`  would be undersood as an octal number.)

Comment: `01` is **not** understood as an octal number when given as an exponent. In other words `1e011` is `1e+11`.

Comment: @torazaburo: I am free to define my convention.

Comment: Indeed you are. I often do that myself. When I do, I try to define conventions which are subtly different from any known conventions. I find that keeps people on their toes.